# Differentiability of a Complex Piecewise Function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

We have a complex function
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2e^z -2}{z} & z\neq0\\ 
\frac{1}{2} & z=0 \\ 
\end{cases} \\ $$

is it differentiable at $z=0$?

i've tried this:

$$f'(z)=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {\frac{2e^z -2}{z} - \frac{1}{2}} {z}\\
       =\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {4e^z -4-z}{2z^2}$$

i know i have to dismiss the $z^2$ right? after this i don't know how to solve this

Comment: If you want to avoid your question being closed, you should probably give some context or say what you've tried. People on here aren't keen on just handing out answers for people's homework if it's not clear that they've at least given it some thought (and rightly so.)

Comment: In any case, as a hint, just try using the limit definition of the derivative and seeing what you get.

Comment: i've tried to use the limit definition

Comment: Then edit the question to show where that's taken you

Comment: okay i edited it

Comment: Good. Now are you aware L'Hopital's rule works for complex limits?

Comment: i'm afraid that i wasn't allowed to solve this with L' Hopital's so i tried to avoid it, but i'm open to do L' Hopital's if needed

Comment: I tried to do it with L' Hopital's rule and i got $e^0$ which is 1, is that right?

Comment: I think you used L'Hopital's one too many times: see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the limit is of the form $\frac00$, we can use L'Hopital's rule to simplify the limit a little:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{4e^z - z - 4}{2z^2} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{4e^z - 1}{4z}$$

Notice we can't use L'Hopital's again because the numerator now approaches $3.$ Now suppose we approached $0$ via the path $z(t) = t$ as $t$ approaches $0$ from both sides:

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{4e^t - 1}{t} \to \infty$$
$$\lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{4e^t - 1}{t} \to -\infty$$

The limit does not exist on one path, so the limit cannot exist.

Comment: oh yeah right sorry my mistake, thank you so much :)

Comment: No worries. I've got an alternative method on the way as well if you'd like to look at it

Comment: i'd like too! may i see your alternative method?

Comment: Working on it, I'm gonna put it in a second answer because they go down pretty distinct paths

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about this is to check for continuity: if differentiability implies continuity, then by contrapositive, a lack of continuity implies a lack of differentiability.

So, let's take the limit of the function as $z \to 0,$ noting again that our limit is of the form $\frac00.$

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{2e^z - 2}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{2e^z}{1} = 2.$$

So $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z) = 2,$ but $f(0) = \frac12,$ so $f(z)$ is not continuous (and therefore not differentiable) at the origin.

Comment: oh right, thankyou for reminding me we can use the differentiablity $\rightarrow$ continuity theorem, thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Of course, have a nice day